# Binary array using V8 engine

Tags: arrays, type-conversion, v8

I have an array of bytes defined as

```
unsigned char ptr = new unsigned char[1024];
fillWithSomething(ptr, 1024);
```

Then, I need to store the `ptr` variable in a `Local< Array>` variable of V8 Engine or another kind of V8 data type.
Currently, I am converting the array of bytes into a string in order to store in a  `Local< String>` variable, but this approach is inefficient to my application.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATED (thanks to Vyacheslav Egorov)

I test the solution with an external array but I can't use it on my node.js server code. I have the following code (on my extension side C++):

```
Handle<Object> array = Object::New();
array->SetIndexedPropertiesToExternalArrayData(getBytes(), kExternalUnsignedByteArray, bytesSize);
return array;
```

My question is, How I can use the `array` variable in my server code (javascript) to call the function `GetIndexedPropertiesExternalArrayData()`.

Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

The most efficient way is to use *external arrays*:

```
v8::Handle<v8::Object> external_array = v8::Object::New();
external_array->SetIndexedPropertiesToExternalArrayData(ptr, v8::kExternalUnsignedByteArray, 1024);
```

Good example of external arrays API usage (including lifetime management) can be found in `d8.cc`: https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/7a0c55bd0d07135ce317f0e95909120eaafd5973/src/d8.cc#L394-L591

Comment: Вячеслав, would you please create minimal example to demonstrate the usage of external arrays? Because so far it seems that only commiters to V8 understand how to use them. Digging into d8, without proper background knowledge is just painful and useless.

Comment: @exebook it's hard to create a more minimal example than two lines of code above.

Comment: `template <typename T> class test {};` is also minimal, but will not explain what is template. I am using embedded V8 for about a year, I cannot understand how to use the above minimal example. The function has a long name and maybe someone may think self explanatory, but I expect to be able to access this array from JS after those lines been executed. But no, array is empty on JS side. Maybe I expect the wrong result. Either way it is not clear (to me).

Comment: @exebook what do you mean by empty? after doing `SetIndexedPropertiesToExternalArrayData` like above elements 0 to 1023 of the `external_array` should map to respective bytes of the memory region pointed by `ptr`. Nothing else will change (e.g. object will not get length property).

Comment: @exebook In simple words: `obj->SetIndexedPropertiesToExternalArrayData(ptr, type, l)` attaches region of memory pointed by `ptr` as an elements storage to the JS object `obj`. When you read/write an element between `0` to `l - 1` V8 will go fetch it/store it in the respective part of that region. Concrete type and size of each element is determined by `type`. E.g.  `v8::kExternalUnsignedByteArray` corresponds to array of bytes and `v8::kExternalFloat64Array` to array of double precision floating point values.

Comment: ok, now it works for me, very simple indeed. thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider using a socalled backingStore, which you create from your original data.

```
    v8::isolate iso = your v8 isolate;
    std::string val = "theBinaryData";
    auto store = v8::ArrayBuffer::NewBackingStore(iso, val.size());
    memcpy(store->Data(), val.c_str(), val.size());
    auto ab = v8::ArrayBuffer::New(iso, std::move(store));
    auto uint8Array = v8::Uint8Array::New(ab, 0, val.size());
```

This way you created a UInt8Array which can process further in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

like Vyacheslav Egorov already answered

```
  obj->SetIndexedPropertiesToExternalArrayData(data,
                                           kExternalUnsignedByteArray,
                                           length);
```

is the right answer.
If you need more examples you can check out https://github.com/joyent/node
they use lots of v8 functionallity.

just `grep -nrw ".*SetIndexedPropertiesToExternalArrayData.*" "."` in the /src folder of the project and you will get lots of examples for `SetIndexedPropertiesToExternalArrayData`